# Rename character column names with a sequence of integers in R?

Tags: r, regex, replace, rename

I got a matrix with col names B1 - B125, and I want to replace/rename those col names with a sequence/numeric vector (starting from 200 until 825, increasing by 5, thus 125 steps).

```
char_col_names <- (here are my col names B1 - B125) #length 125
seq_vector <- seq(200, 825, 5) #numeric vector with length 125

library(gsubfn)
renamed_cols <- gsubfn("B{1}0-9{1,3}",as.list(seq_vector),colnames(char_col_names))
```

That doesn't work, as it returns me the exact same col names I already got, a list of "B1", "B2, "B3" and so on instead of "200", "205, "210"...

Any ideas? 
Help is greatly appreciated... stuck here.

Comment: returns the exact same

Comment: do you know the order will be sequential?  If so, why not just reassign the column names?  `colnames(x) <- as.character(seq_vector)`

Comment: note that `length(seq(200, 825, 5)) == 126` not `125`. This works: `colnames(char_col_names) = seq(205, 825, 5)`

Comment: got damn it that's it... haha easier than thought of! many thanks